# How to ensure that rowversion on parent updates when a child entity is modified

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm building an API using Entity Framework against a SQL Server Database. I have 2 Tables/Entities like follows:

```
ParentTable{
  Id INT Primary Key
  RowVersion BYTE
}

ChildTable{
   ParentKey INT Foreign Key (ParentTable)
   SomeField NVARCHAR
   SomeOtherField NVARCHAR
}

class ParentEntity{
   string someOtherField
   ICollection<ChildEntity> childReference
}
```

On saving the Parent object, I want to check the Rowversion to handle any concurrency issues. However I'm finding that when only child entities are modified in the parent object, that the rowversion on the parent does not change. How would I get around this?

Comment: Why do you need to force the `rowversion` of the parent to change? If the parent's data hasn't changed, then there's no reason for the value of its `rowversion` to change. This has the smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Because the entities are related and if the child value changes then I want to reload what the user sees. It's basically an object/objectlangstring type relationship. If the langstring changes for the object, and a user tries saving with their own changes before seeing what the newest updates were, I want to be able to reflect that

Comment: But there's no need to reload the parent, it's unchanged.

Comment: But the changes to the child are saved through saving the parent.

Comment: But the parent isn't inherently changing so, again, the parent's `rowversion` does not need to change. The value or `rowversion` changing means that the value has **changed**; if it hasn't then it shouldn't update; which it is not because no change has occured.

Comment: Right. Is there a way to work around this? I would still need some way of being able to check if the model that the user has when they save is out of date, if only the child entity on the model is changed. Short of updating the parent schema to include a timestamp parameter, is there any other way to accomplish the given task?

Comment: Create triggers on all child tables, update the parent with a null update (`SET ID = ID`), ???, profit.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked.

I don't think the people who responded initially conceptualized the problem pingOfDoom was facing. There are definitely situations where you need to know a nested child has changed and reflect that on the parent record. In my case a user profile where a skill was added or deleted from a nested child list. I still need to trigger a concurrency warning if another user tries to make a change to the parent, otherwise EFCore will simply add or delete the child list item that was removed or added by another user.

The solution I used to the same problem was to add a LastUpdated DateTime field to the parent. Whenever I call my logic to save the parent and its children the LastUpdated field is updated and concurrency works as expected. It's useful for auditing purposes and solves the problem without having to add triggers to all the children database tables.

Comment: It is called an Application-managed concurrency token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#application-managed-concurrency-tokens) in terms of EF. The DB field is not a rowversion in this case